# ReactSelect - selected values show in dropdown menu in MultiSelect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

In MultiSelect, on selecting the dropdown menu items removing from menu and showing in selected lists

https://codesandbox.io/s/8qw3p?module=/example.js&file=/example.js

can we keep the selected items in dropdown menu itself and show selected.

can we keep Ocean in dropdown menu even it's selected.

[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFqdI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You'll have to use the `hideSelectedOptions` property:

```
  <Select
    isMulti
    hideSelectedOptions={false}
  />
```